# YouTube API v3.0 CommentsThread.list proccessing failuer issue

Tags: youtube-api

When I send a comments thread. List request to the YouTube API 
I get the following exception "But not for all videos":

```
Google.GoogleApiException: Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
The API server failed to successfully process the request.
```

While this can be a transient error, it usually indicates that the requests input is invalid. Check the structure of the `commentThread` resource in the request body to ensure that it is valid. [400].

And for those videos I double checked the inputs sent with the request and I
make the request with the same data directly from the YouTube API requests trial section but everything goes right!

I want to know why this request becomes valid on some video ID's but invalid on the others ?
I'll appreciate any help.

Here is the full written log: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Google.GoogleApiException: Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
The API server failed to successfully process the request. While this can be a transient error, it usually indicates that the requests input is invalid. Check the structure of the `commentThread` resource in the request body to ensure that it is valid. [400]
Errors [
    Message[The API server failed to successfully process the request. While this can be a transient error, it usually indicates that the requests input is invalid. Check the structure of the `commentThread` resource in the request body to ensure that it is valid.] Location[body - other] Reason[processingFailure] Domain[youtube.commentThread]
]

at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccess(Task task)
   at Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest`1.d__0.MoveNext() in c:\ApiaryDotnet\default\Src\GoogleApis\Apis\Requests\ClientServiceRequest.cs:line 0
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Comment: Can you provide code snippets and logs that can help with checking out the issue?

Comment: I've updated the Question with the full log information

Answer (score 0):

[`CommentThreads.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list#request-body) API doesn't need a request body as indicated in the API reference

> **Request body**
>
> Do not provide a request body when calling this method.

This may have caused the `RequestError` on your call. Try to remove any objects passed when calling this API, hopefully this would fix the issue.

Comment: I'm sending only the video Id, maximum Results to be returned and the next page access token if existed with the call to the API !